# Pandas scatter plot TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot points in a shapefile using `geopandas` and I keep encountering

> TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable

whenever I run the code below. This error disappears when I remove the `colormap` attribute. But I want to change the color of my points and I think `colormap` is helpful for that.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas

shapefile = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file('file.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

base = shapefile.plot(ax=ax)

df.plot.scatter('Long', 'Lat',  c=df['colC'], s=df['colD'], alpha=0.7, ax=base, colormap='viridis')
```

Comment: What are the types stored in `'colC'`?

Comment: Float numbers...

Comment: What happens if you change `c=df['colC']` to `c='colC'`, while keeping the `colormap` argument fixed?

Comment: I encounter the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try direct calls to `matplotlib`. I don't have your dataset to try this with, but try the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shapefile = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file('file.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

shapefile.plot(ax=ax)

x, y, c, s = itemgetter('Long', 'Lat', 'colC', 'colD')(df)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=s, cmap='viridis')
```

Comment: Glad to hear it ! I just realize that it also might have been your specification of `ax=base`. My guess is that `GeoDataFrame.plot` doesn't return an `ax` object. Better to explicitly pass around the *same* `Axes` object to each plotting call you're interested in invoking.